# How can I access this JSON element dynamically in Typescript?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have a data grid which is getting used across the application. I am getting currently selected rowid using the below code.

In HTML:

```
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let ddata of tableData.data; let i = ddata" (click)="setClickedRow(ddata)" [class.active]="ddata.discountauthorizationid == selectedRow">
      <td *ngFor="let dr of tableData.record | paginate: { itemsPerPage: pageItem, currentPage: p }">{{ddata[dr]}}</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

And in `component.ts` file I am doing this:

```
this.selectedRow = ddata.discountauthorizationid;

console.log("You selected!",ddata.discountauthorizationid);
this.dataService.changeMessage(ddata.discountauthorizationid);
```

Now I want to make this access completely dynamic and I have the primary id defined like this

```
@Input() primaryid: string
```

I want to access this `data.(some_primaryid)` just like we access the array using key and assign key using variable. Is it possible? If so how?

Comment: could you show us your data? how could we tell if data.(some_primaryid) would work on your data or not without any example. Your question is incomplete, give us some sample data and show us what type of result you want.

Comment: Sorry for lack of clarity but I have situation where the name of the element will differ with every the module. so it would be like discountid or accountid or userid  and So on. I have already a variable called primaryid which is holding the name of the primaryid.  so if I want to access data.accountid , instead of hard coding I want to use data.[primaryid] or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can access the value.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.primaryId = "userId";
    
    $scope.data = {
       "userId": 1,
       "accountId": 23,
       "testId": 5
    };

  
$scope.changeId = ()=>{
    
   $scope.primaryId = "accountId";
};
}
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   {{primaryId}} is :  {{data[primaryId]}}!
 <button ng-click="changeId()">
  Change ID
 </button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect one. I was looking like this. was Just testing it. Thanks for the confirming my solution. Your answer is precise clear and true :-)

Comment: I have added a button as well for you to show how to access it dynamically

Answer (score 0):

**Update**, according to your comment:

```
class Data {
    public some_primary_id: string;
}

let id = 'some_primary_id'; // id would be your input parameter
let data = <Data>{ some_primary_id: '123' };

alert(data[id]); // 123
```

**Previous Comment:**
I'm not sure if I get your question right but according to your last sentence:

> want to access this data.(some_primaryid) just like we access the array using key and assign key using variable. Is it possible? if so How?

Yes it is possible, you can access properties like that:

```
console.log(ddata['some_primaryid']);
ddata['some_primaryid'] = '123';
```

Comment: Yes you got my point right but instead of static name 'some_primaryid'  can I use ddata[primary_id_var] where primary_id_var holds name of the primary id .

Answer (score 0):

After trying many things. I am able to do it like this. ddata[primary_id_var]. 
I tried ddata[{{primary_id_var}}] but it didn't worked.